# C - A function that calculates the integral of a polynomial

Tags: c, array, calculator

I have written a simple function which takes an array of coefficients of a polynomial and then integrates it. My polynomial is represented like this:
$$polynomial[0] + polynomial[1]x + polynomial[2]x^2 + \dots + polynomial[n]x^n$$
And its integral will become: 
$$polynomial[0]x + \frac 1 2 polynomial[1]x^2 + \frac 1 3 polynomial[2] x^3 + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$$

```
#include <stdio.h>

void integrate(double *polynomial, double *buff, int number_of_terms) {
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_terms; i++) {
        buff[i+1] = polynomial[i] / (i+1);
    }
    buff[0] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    double polynomial[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3
    double buff[5];
    integrate(polynomial, buff, 4);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%f, ",  buff[i]);
    }
    //Output: 0.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000
    //0 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4
}
```

The problem with my solution is that I need  to set the value at index zero manually - I don't think this is a good practice and therefore would like to somehow wrap the 0th index into the formula in the loop. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Thank you @TobySpeight. I have edited my question and added a minimal working example. Still, why does my question receive downvotes?

Comment: Thanks for providing more context.  Did you choose `0` for the constant term for a particular reason (e.g. to make the integral evaluate to zero at `x==0`)?  Or is it an arbitrary choice?

Comment: The integration constant is missing from the second formula and that is what `buff[0] = 0;` and this post is about.  Recommend adding that to the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `buff` is not a meaningful name. Call it `integral` perhaps?
- I'd use a more mathematical `degree` rather than `number_of_terms`.
- In your approach (going from lowest to highest degree) `polynomial` and `buff` may never overlap. `restrict` them:

  ```
  void integrate(double * restrict polynomial, double * restrict buff, int number_of_terms)
  ```
- I see no other way to deal with the integration constant but passing it as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Minor considerations to add to [@vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/187880/29485) good answer.

1. Amend `double *polynomial` --> `const double *polynomial` to better convey function's interface and allow calling with a `const` array.
2. `size_t` is the "Goldilocks" type to use for array indexing and array math without being excessively wide nor limiting.
3. Re-order parameters.  `polynomial` goes with `number_of_terms` yet is separated by `buff`.  Many  C library functions list the result pointer parameters first "output" and then the "input".

   ```
   //                v-----------------------------v
   integrate(double *polynomial, double *buff, int number_of_terms)
   ```

---

Putting this together:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void integrate(double * restrict integrated, const double * restrict polynomial, 
    size_t degree, double c) {
  integrated[0] = c;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < degree; i++) {
    integrated[i+1] = polynomial[i] / (i+1);
  }
}
```